# Letting a friend use computer to access his Dropbox account from my computer

Tags: dropbox

I already have a Dropbox account. Suppose if one of my friends want to check and upload some files to their Dropbox account from my computer.

Would it be okay to let them use my computer for that purpose?

Is there such a restriction that only I should use the Dropbox on my own computer to login and upload files?

Comment: Create a new user in order to do this

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely no problem. I would suggest their web interface. If you tried to install the client and then use it it might get a little weird and it could try to download his stuff to your comp but uploading through the web no problem.

I would also suggest an incognito or inprivate mode to prevent your computer storing his password and not saving cookies / having your password etc ...

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem. As PsychoData already suggested the web interface is fine for this purpose and also for downloading files from his account.

If you have to exchange data like this more regularly, I suggest you should create a [shared folder](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en). This allows you to drop files at a location in your Dropbox folder. Your friend can then access (read, manipulate and even delete) it from his Dropbox account as well.

You should not connect your Dropbox program to another account. This will lead to a multitude of inconveniences.